# Changing plot label sizes in R, cex is not working

Tags: r

I am making a very simple plot in R and would like the change the font size on the y-axis (the years).  I have used all the cex. commands, and can change everything except these years.

Here is my matrix (inputm):

```
     2010  2011
CC 0.5550 0.480
P  3.6700 3.865
PF 1.4625 1.685
```

And my code:

```
barplot(inputm,beside=T, horiz=TRUE, xlim=c(-7,7), 
col=c("black","blue","red"), xlab="Mg C/ha", cex.axis=2)
```

I can get the x-axis labels to change, but not the y.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `cex.names` as in

```
barplot(VADeaths, horiz=TRUE, cex.names=0.85)
```

Which produces

[image]