# R histogram missing negative x labels

Tags: r, axis-labels

I am trying to generate a histogram in R, but some of the x labels are missing. 
Here is the code I wrote:

```
> tmp <- hist(x, breaks=-3.5:(max(x)+1), xaxt="n", right=FALSE, xlab="log(MRS)",main="Pairwise Family-Health")

> axis(1, at=tmp$mids, labels=-3.5:max(x))
```

(The x values should be -3.5,-2.5,-1.5,-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, and the bars centering at these values.)

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks!

Comment: R will not print labels on top of each other and right now there is not enough room to print all the labels. Make your plot wider so there is more room.

Comment: related qs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416992/names-on-the-x-axis-of-barplot-in-r) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596772/questions-about-axes-and-mtext) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899086/changing-plot-label-sizes-in-r-cex-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the methods suggested in the comments (making the plot bigger, or making the text smaller), you may also want to look at the `staxlab` function in the plotrix package which automates a stacked label approach (puts the labels alternating on 2 or more lines to include more labels but still prevent overlap).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `gap.axis` argument within the axis function. So something like,

```
axis(side = 1, at = seq(-500000, 500000, by = 100000), gap.axis = 0.25)`
```

helped me when I had the same problem.